# How can I investigate these mystery Django crashes?

Tags: mysql, django, apache, profiling

A Django site (hosted on Webfaction) that serves around 950k pageviews a month is experiencing crashes that I haven't been able to figure out how to debug. At unpredictable intervals (averaging about once per day, but not at the same time each day), all requests to the site start to hang/timeout, making the site totally inaccessible until we restart Apache. These requests appear in the frontend access logs as 499s, but do not appear in our application's logs at all.

In poring over the server logs (including those generated by django-timelog) I can't seem to find any pattern in which pages are hit right before the site goes down. For the most recent crash, all the pages that are hit right before the site went down seem to be standard render-to-response operations using templates that seem pretty straightforward and work well the rest of the time. The requests right before the crash do not seem to take longer according to timelog, and I haven't been able to replicate the crashes intentionally via load testing.

Webfaction says that isn't a case of overrunning our allowed memory usage or else they would notify us. One thing to note is that the database is not being restarted (just the app/Apache) when we bring the site back up.

How would you go about investigating this type of recurring issue? It seems like there must be a line of code somewhere that's hanging - do you have any suggestions about a process for finding it?

Comment: What external dependencies does your site have? Does it use an API that is unreachable sometimes? Do you have an infinite loop somewhere? It could be any number of things, depending on how complex your app is.

Comment: I've had rather more joy with gunicorn on webfaction than apache. You might like to try that - it also has more in the way of debugging tools for when you're desperate (including the ability to trace every line of code in selected modules).

Answer (score 0):

Since you can't really describe what the failure conditions are until you can replicate the crash, you may need to force the situation with `ab` ([apache benchmark](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/programs/ab.html)). If you don't want to do this with your production site you might replicate the site in a subdomain. Warning: `ab` can beat the ever loving crap out of a server, so RTM. You might also want to give the WF admins a heads up about what you are going to do.

**Update for comment:**

I was suggesting using the *exact same machine* so that the subdomain name was the only difference. Given that you used a different *machine* there are a large number of subtle (and not so subtle) environmental things that could tweak you away from getting the error to manifest. If the new machine is OK, and if you are willing to walk away from the problem without actually solving it, you might simply make it your production machine and be happy. Personally I tend to obsess about stuff like this, but then again I'm also retired and have plenty of time to play with my toes. :-)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I set up a subdomain a couple of days ago for load testing the app on another WF machine (and even ran load testing on the main site during low usage hours) but couldn't crash it. (I was using blitz.io as opposed to ab, but am open to using any tool). Since I couldn't crash it w/ load, my current thought was that it must be a specific line of code that's hanging.

Answer (score 0):

I once had some issues like this, and it basically boiled down to my misunderstanding of thread-safety within django middleware.  Basically the django middleware is I believe a singleton that is shared among all threads, and these threads were thrashing with the values set on a custom middleware class I had. My solution was to rewrite my middleware to not use instance or class attributes that changed, and to switch the critical parts of my application to not use threads at all with my uwsgi server as these seemed to be an overall performance downside for my app. Threaded uwsgi setups seem to work best when you have views that may complete at different intervals (some long running views and some fast ones).